# Invalid Fernet key when an existing yet exited airflow container is again started

Tags: docker, encryption, cryptography, airflow

I Have dockerized airflow service with a `FERNET_KEY` as an environment variable exported using a `.env` file(which also includes other environment variables apart from `FERNET_KEY`).

When I build and run the docker container, the airflow service runs as expected and then I go to connections and set up my AWS connections in the airflow UI as mentioned here https://airflow.apache.org/howto/connection/aws.html . So far so good. Now, I deliberately stop the docker container and then start the container again and go to airflow UI--> Connections to see if my AWS connection settings are still there(which I configured before stopping the container).

But, here is what happens. when I go to see `aws_default` settings in  airflow UI, I see an error as below

```
Ooops.

                      ____/ (  (    )   )  \___
                     /( (  (  )   _    ))  )   )\
                   ((     (   )(    )  )   (   )  )
                 ((/  ( _(   )   (   _) ) (  () )  )
                ( (  ( (_)   ((    (   )  .((_ ) .  )_
               ( (  )    (      (  )    )   ) . ) (   )
              (  (   (  (   ) (  _  ( _) ).  ) . ) ) ( )
              ( (  (   ) (  )   (  ))     ) _)(   )  )  )
             ( (  ( \ ) (    (_  ( ) ( )  )   ) )  )) ( )
              (  (   (  (   (_ ( ) ( _    )  ) (  )  )   )
             ( (  ( (  (  )     (_  )  ) )  _)   ) _( ( )
              ((  (   )(    (     _    )   _) _(_ (  (_ )
               (_((__(_(__(( ( ( |  ) ) ) )_))__))_)___)
               ((__)        \\||lll|l||///          \_))
                        (   /(/ (  )  ) )\   )
                      (    ( ( ( | | ) ) )\   )
                       (   /(| / ( )) ) ) )) )
                     (     ( ((((_(|)_)))))     )
                      (      ||\(|(|)|/||     )
                    (        |(||(||)||||        )
                      (     //|/l|||)|\\ \     )
                    (/ / //  /|//||||\\  \ \  \ _)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Node: 64e7a509837f
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_admin/base.py", line 69, in inner
    return self._run_view(f, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_admin/base.py", line 368, in _run_view
    return fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_admin/model/base.py", line 2125, in edit_view
    form = self.edit_form(obj=model)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_admin/model/base.py", line 1340, in edit_form
    return self._edit_form_class(get_form_data(), obj=obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wtforms/form.py", line 212, in __call__
    return type.__call__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_admin/form/__init__.py", line 16, in __init__
    super(BaseForm, self).__init__(formdata=formdata, obj=obj, prefix=prefix, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wtforms/form.py", line 278, in __init__
    self.process(formdata, obj, data=data, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wtforms/form.py", line 127, in process
    if obj is not None and hasattr(obj, name):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 353, in __get__
    retval = self.descriptor.__get__(instance, owner)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/connection.py", line 155, in get_password
    return fernet.decrypt(bytes(self._password, 'utf-8')).decode()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cryptography/fernet.py", line 171, in decrypt
    raise InvalidToken
cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken
```

I may be missing some concept about Fernet keys. Do I have to generate new fernet key every single time my docker container starts? If so, how should I generate on the fly when docker is building?
The `FERNET_KEY` which I injected in to `.env` file is actually generated in my local computer and copied over to `.env` file(FERNET_KEY=4EPOSLXXXXXXXXXXXIERu=) which docker is using

Comment: If you want to make sure existing connections work, you should always use the same `FERNET_KEY`, or you can't decrypt your credentials. There must be some other issue. Try shelling into your docker container to check if the environment variables do match. You should also check Airflow's configurations.

Comment: Hey, @Kingz did you solve the issue? I am facing the exactly same situation and could not find any answers.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't need to generate a new key on the fly. You maybe missing something, have you tried to connect to your docker machine and print the FERNET_KEY from the terminal to check if it is not really been loaded?

```
$ docker exec -it <CONTAINER ID> bash
(now, inside the container) # echo ${FERNET_KEY}
```

If it is not the same as your env file there is something wrong. Are you using a docker-compose environment? If so, you also need to the following to docker-compose.yml:

```
environment:
    - FERNET_KEY=${FERNET_KEY}
```

Comment: The `FERNET_KEY` is present in the docker container as an env variable. But I think when I stop and start the container, that `FERNET_KEY` is not the one which airflow web server is expecting because at that point it is assuming a default setting from fernet_key=${fernet_key} in airflow.cfg file. I don't know what's going on, but this is my assumption

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I'm using a mac and running the containers with docker-compose.

I solved it by creating a new FERNET_KEY

```
python -c "from cryptography.fernet import Fernet; print(Fernet.generate_key().decode())"
```

and adding the line with the new generated key (including the final "=" to) to my **~/.bash_profile** file in this way:
`export FERNET_KEY="new_generated_key"`.

After that, I added

```
environment:
    - FERNET_KEY=${FERNET_KEY}
```

to my docker-compose (under the service of the webserver of course), like Renato was saying above.